# How to Access Attribute value through ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

html:

1.js file:

```
{
    name: 'Number 1',
    value: '1',
    url: 'img/1.png'
}
```

script using for Ajax Call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "1.js",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache:false,
        success: function(data){
            var x = data;
            $(".first").html("<img src="+x.url+" />");
            $(".first").html("<p>"+x.name+"</p>");
            return(data);
        }
    });
});
```

I am getting the response as "undefined" in DOM and in "Network (F12 option) Preview"- undefined: 1.
Also I am getting the response in "Network - Response" as

```
{
    name: 'Number 1',
    value: '1',
    url: 'img/1.png'
}
```

Can some one help me to get the values of name, Value and url values ?

Comment: Seems that your JSON code is wrong in `1.js` (http://jsonlint.com/). Try this one: `{
    "name": "Number1",
    "value": "1",
    "url": "img/1.png"
}`

Comment: Thanks, i tried that before and it is working. Is it not possible to get the same with below code(not having quotes to left side values) and in ajax call "dataType:" can be anything.{
    name: 'Number 1',
    value: '1',
    url: 'img/1.png'
}